# How can I grab the geographical area of a user who is posting on my site and store it in a database

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation

I  would like to know the code which can enable me  to  get a person’s physical address whenever he visits my website . now the code I have is for getting the IP address .
Bellow is the code I would like someone to give me a crew rolling on what I have

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: GeoIP location detection could be of help. I have tagged your question with geolocation.

Comment: you could use the free [maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/api) API, it checks the location based on the IP address, go take a look.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fields for security table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204412/fields-for-security-table) - Please do not duplicate but edit questions. If a question is closed, it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the ip.

use this snippet in php:

```
function GetUserIp() {
$ip = "";
if(isset($_SERVER)) {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else { $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
} else { if ( getenv( 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP' ) ) {
    $ip = getenv( 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP' );
} elseif ( getenv( 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' ) ) {
    $ip = getenv( 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' );
} else { $ip = getenv( 'REMOTE_ADDR' );
}
}
if(strstr($ip,',')){
    $ip = array_shift(explode(',',$ip));
}
return $ip;
}
```

once you get the ip you have to compare with a list ip-locations in order to get the location. for getting this list try to google it.

Answer (score 0):

Get your users ip address using

```
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Then the best approach is to use a GeoIP webservice. You could also use a local GeoIP database. [ip2location](http://www.ip2location.com/developers/) runs one such service that has been around for long and you can find apis for most popular languages.

Modern browsers do you the option to send the location, but this is optional and may very often be disabled by your users.

Comment: Thnaks guys for your help I will start from there